# Location of SQLite initialization? (iOS)

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I am contributing to an open source iOS app and I need to insert rows into the SQLite database when it is first being initialized. But since I don't have any experience with SQL I do not know which file I should do this in, I have been looking through the project for hours to find where the data is being passed in with no success. This is the table where I am trying to add rows. I need 4 rows in total with the names being avatar_clothes_01 (already there), avatar_clothes_02, avatar_clothes_03, and avatar_clothes_04. Thanks so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Are you using FMDB? to do this?

Comment: Yes! The files are FMDatabase.h, FMResultSet.m, FMResultSet.h, FMDatabase.m, FMDatabaseAdditions.h, FMDatabaseAdditions.m, FMDatabasePool.h, FMDatabasePool.m, FMDatabaseQueue.m, FMDatabaseQueue.h, and FMDB.h if you need to know those as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

> Database queue definition

```
/**
 Database Queue object.
 */
var oDatabaseQueue : FMDatabaseQueue;
```

> Init part

```
init() {

    let oDirPaths     = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true);
    let sDocsDir      = oDirPaths[0];
    let oDatabasePath = sDocsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("databaseName" + ".db");
    self.oDatabase    = FMDatabase(path: oDatabasePath as String);
    self.oDatabaseQueue = FMDatabaseQueue(path: oDatabasePath as String);
}
```

> Inserting in your db, should be better if you pass your model as parameter and adjust the arguments according

```
func insertTest(id:Int,name:String,points:Int,purchased:Bool){
        self.oDatabaseQueue.inDatabase() { oDatabase in

            if (oDatabase?.open())! {

                var sSql = "INSERT INTO Clothes (";
                sSql = sSql + "ID,";
                sSql = sSql + "Name,";
                sSql = sSql + "Points,";
                sSql = sSql + "Purchased";
                sSql = sSql + ") VALUES (";
                sSql = sSql + "?,";
                sSql = sSql + "?,";
                sSql = sSql + "?,";
                sSql = sSql + "?";
                sSql = sSql + ")";
                Int(purchased)
                let oArguments : [Any] = [
                    id,
                    name,
                    points,
                    Int(purchased)
                ];

                if (database!.executeUpdate(sSql, withArgumentsIn: oArguments)) {

                    database!.commit()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which file should I put this code into? Sorry for so many questions, I am a total beginner.

Comment: You can use a singleton class with all your database functions @Erika

Comment: Let me know if you need further advice @Erika